# How to transform regexp to list

Tags: python, string, split

I've got a regexp string with only | and () like :

(Hello|Hi) my name is (Bob|Robert)

And I would like to have the complete list of string who match the regexp :

Hello my name is Bob
Hello my name is Robert
Hi my name is Bob
Hi my name is Robert

Is it a tool (librairy) who already do this ?

My first problem is to split the regexp string into a array of array like :

```
[['Hello','Hi'],'my name is' ,['Bob','Robert']]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try exrex, think that should work for you

Simple script

```
import exrex
print(list(exrex.generate('(Hello|Hi) my name is (Bob|Robert)')))
```

Output

```
→ python new_test.py
['Hello my name is Bob', 'Hello my name is Robert', 'Hi my name is Bob', 'Hi my 
name is Robert']
```

https://github.com/asciimoo/exrex

Answer (score 0):

Do it with regex:-)

```
re.split(r"(\(.+?\|.+?\))",s)
Out: ['', '(Hello|Hi)', ' my name is ', '(Bob|Robert)', '']
# and for each string in the list:
re.split(r"\((.+?)\|(.+?)\)",'(Hello|Hi)')
Out: ['', 'Hello', 'Hi', '']
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can try below solution, here I haven't imported any module. The only functions used are `strip, split and replace`**

```
input_string = "(Hello|Hi) my name is (Bob|Robert)"
split_string = (input_string.replace("("," ").replace(")"," ")).split("  ")
print ([i.strip().split("|") for i in split_string])

#Output --> [['Hello', 'Hi'], ['my name is'], ['Bob', 'Robert']]
```

---

I hope this helps!

---

**If you need the final solution to your query then use below code:**

```
from itertools import product
input_string = "(Hello|Hi) my name is (Bob|Robert)"
split_string = (input_string.replace("("," ").replace(")"," ")).split("  ")
jj = [i.strip().split("|") for i in split_string]
kk = list(product(*jj))
print ([" ".join(i) for i in kk])
#output --> ['Hello my name is Bob', 'Hello my name is Robert', 'Hi my name is Bob', 'Hi my name is Robert']
```

The above code will also work for: input_string = "(Hello|Hi|Hey) my (name|naam) is (Bob|Robert)"